# How to make Scrollable Label in List Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionviewsource

I have a List view with fixed Row Height. Inside List view there is Label with large description. I am trying to make this label scroll able. Can anyone help please.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceList, Mode=TwoWay}" RowHeight="100">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ServiceModel">
        <ViewCell>
            <ScrollView
                Margin="0"
                Padding="0"
                HeightRequest="50">
                <Label
                    LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                    Style="{StaticResource blackColorLabel}"
                    Text="{Binding ServiceDescription}" />
            </ScrollView>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple scrolls, ListView has its own scroll adding a scrollView to it just adds issues! Can your requirement not be achieved some other way

Comment: `Listview` already scrolls event. Please not use `ScrollView` in `Listview`, the scroll gestures get confused as to where to target.

Comment: Can you suggest me any other way? I understand that List View and Scroll View do not work together. Any third party plugin or something which enable me to display large amount of text in each cell. I can not change each cell size. Its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't nest scrollviews because the behavior is erratic. You can use `BindableLayout` though.

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceList}">
<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ServiceModel">
            <ScrollView
                Margin="0"
                Padding="0"
                HeightRequest="50">
                <Label
                    LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                    Style="{StaticResource blackColorLabel}"
                    Text="{Binding ServiceDescription}" />
            </ScrollView>
    </DataTemplate>
</BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
```

`RowHeight` is not a thing for `BindableLayouts`, but you could probably wrap your Label in a `ContentView` and set the `HeightReqeust` of the `ContentView` to `100`. Or maybe even just set your `Label Height Request` to `100` and see what that does.